# How deal with org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core.Mat memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

This is how I use org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core.Mat,core code:

```
// image binary
byte[] bytes;
try (PointerScope pointerScope = new PointerScope();
     Mat originImage = org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_imgcodecs.imdecode(new Mat(bytes), opencv_imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR)) {

    // my business logic

    pointerScope.deallocate();
    
}
```

I found that the off-heap memory used by the Mat object will not be recycled, causing a memory leak. After the program runs for a period of time, OOM will occur.

I tried using the mat.release() method but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an additional `Mat` object that is not automatically released:

```
/*...*/ new Mat(bytes) /*...*/
```

You should separately include it into the try with resources:

```
// image binary
byte[] bytes;
try (PointerScope pointerScope = new PointerScope();
     Mat data = new Mat(bytes);
     Mat originImage = org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_imgcodecs.imdecode(data, opencv_imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR)) {

    // my business logic

    pointerScope.deallocate();
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after I modified it according to your suggestion, it still won't be released automatically.